# Creating OMXCodec encoder in HW mode

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, hardware-acceleration, stagefright

I'm trying to implement HW-accelrated H264 video encoding on Android ICS 4.0.4. Since MediaCodec class is not available I have to use stagefright API. But when I put **HardwareCodecsOnly** flag, OMXCodec::Create always returns NULL.
If I call OMXCodec::findMatchingCodecs() with flag kHardwareCodecsOnly, I got following list:
- OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.H264E
- OMX.qcom.7x30.video.encoder.avc
- OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc
- OMX.TI.Video.encoder
- OMX.Nvidia.h264.encoder
- OMX.SEC.AVC.Encoder

so I guess it means that HW-encoding supported by hardware.

When I put no flags in **OMXCodec::Create** - codec created well, but I guess it is in software mode
(btw, how can I check- which codec exactly was created?)

Browsing OMXCodec sources I've found interesting lines:

```
if (createEncoder) {            
sp<MediaSource> softwareCodec =
 InstantiateSoftwareEncoder(componentName, source, meta);
    if (softwareCodec != NULL) {   
    LOGV("Successfully allocated software codec '%s'", componentName);
    return softwareCodec;            
}        
}
```

it looks like for Encoder it always tries to instance Software codec first.
What am I doing wrong? Any help wil be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Here's a code of OMXCodec creation:

```
         mClient = new OMXClient();
        mClient->connect();
     logger->log("mClient.connect();");

      enc_meta = new MetaData;
     // frame size of target video file
    int width = 640; //720;
    int height = 480;
     int kFramerate = 15;
     int kVideoBitRate = 500000;
     int kIFramesIntervalSec = 5;
     int32_t colorFormat = OMX_COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar;

    enc_meta->setCString(kKeyMIMEType, MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC); //MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_MPEG4); //MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_H263);//MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC);
    enc_meta->setInt32(kKeyWidth, width);
    enc_meta->setInt32(kKeyHeight, height);
    enc_meta->setInt32(kKeyFrameRate, kFramerate);
    enc_meta->setInt32(kKeySampleRate, 44100);
    enc_meta->setInt32(kKeyBitRate, kVideoBitRate);
    enc_meta->setInt32(kKeyStride, width);
    enc_meta->setInt32(kKeySliceHeight, height);
    enc_meta->setInt32(kKeyIFramesInterval, kIFramesIntervalSec);
    enc_meta->setInt32(kKeyColorFormat, colorFormat);

  mVideoSource = OMXCodec::Create(
            mClient->interface(), 
            enc_meta,
            true, 
            mSrc, 
            NULL, 
            OMXCodec::kHardwareCodecsOnly ); 

    logger->log("OMXCodec_CREATED result: %d", (mVideoSource!=NULL) ? 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Android` `ICS 4.0.4`, the codec registration was static i.e. all codecs were registered as part of an array `KEncoderInfo` as can be found [here](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp#171).

The methodology to differentiate between `hardware` and `software` codecs is pretty simple. If the component name doesn't start with `OMX`, then it is construed to be a `software` codec as shown in the[`IsSoftwareCodec`](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp#IsSoftwareCodec) method.

Since you are trying an `AVC` encoder, the software codec if created would be `AVCEncoder` as can be found from it's [`Factory`](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp#92) reference.

To check which codec was created, you can enable logs in `OMXCodec.cpp` file by removing the comment as `#define LOG_NDEBUG 0` in [this](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp#17) line, save and recompile to build `libstagefright.so` which could be used to generate the logs on `logcat` screen.

**EDIT:**

In case of `rtsp` streaming, one needs to enable the logs in [`ACodec.cpp`](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp) .

One needs to ascertain if `libstagefrighthw.so` is present in `/system/lib` which will register the `OMX` core with the `Stagefright` framework.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation. But the problem actually was - why it is not possible to create Hardware-accelerated codec. I guess HW-cdec is not supported if stagefrighthw.so file missed in /system/lib folder. Is that right?

Comment: @user2199593.. If there is no `libstagefrighthw.so`, then the `OMX` core is not initialized and hence, no hardware components i.e. `OMX` components can be instantiated. So your suspicion is right.

Comment: @Ganesh I have a similar question about using h264 to decode streaming frames in annexb format... can you reply pl ?

Comment: @nikhilelite.. I have updated my response. Please let me know if it answers your query. Else, please elaborate a little more on your problem.